# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'context._currentValue = currentValue')

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, npm, cocoapods

Following error occurred when run react-native project on iOS. This project works well in android. In terminal project build successfully without any error. But when app launched it will crash after flash screen.

[image]
   [image]

Package.json

```
{
"name": "TestProject",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "link": "^0.1.5",
    "o": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.3",
    "react-native": "^0.54.3",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.4",
    "react-native-checkbox-field": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-input": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-exit-app": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^4.0.14",
    "react-native-fontawesome": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "^5.6.3",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.12",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.19.3",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.0.16",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.19.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-picker": "^4.3.7",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.31",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.3.2",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "realm": "^2.13.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "save": "^2.3.2",
    "watchman": "^0.1.8",
    "yarn": "^1.9.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-beta.5"
},
"babel": {
    "presets": [
        "es2015"
    ]
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
},
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
        "Fonts",
        "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
}
}
```

Pod file

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'TestProject' do
rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react- 
native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec'

pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', subspecs: [
'ART',
'DevSupport',
'RCTNetwork',
'RCTImage',
'Core',
'CxxBridge',
'RCTActionSheet',
'RCTAnimation',
'RCTGeolocation',
'RCTLinkingIOS',
'RCTNetwork',
'RCTSettings',
'RCTText',
'RCTVibration',
'RCTWebSocket',
 ]
pod 'RSKImageCropper'
pod 'QBImagePickerController'

pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'  
end

post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
    end
  end
  if target.name == "React"
    target.remove_from_project
  end
end
end
```

There aren't any clear description for what causing this error. I would be very grateful if someone can show what is base point which causing this error. Thank you

Comment: Can you scroll down in the red error screen and post a screenshot of the section that is written in lighter font? usually that gives a bit more detail about where the error is originating from

Comment: @Nunchucks I have upload a another image. Please go though it

Answer (score 0):

check https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18695

you need to use specific versions of RN and React to use contexts, HTH